# Buying a duplex with another party, and 1 moves out: Does that party pay more?

Tags: loans

I bought a duplex with another person.  Two houses on the lot, and we both are living in the property.

One decided to move out & rent their  part. Would they still be obligated to pay their half, if the renters don’t pay?

Comment: How was the purchase structured? Separate titles and mortgages for each house? One title and loan for the whole thing? If the latter, do the parties have a written agreement about who pays what?

Comment: The bank wants its money, and rightly goes after the people on the mortgage, expecting them to pony up the cash every month.  Read the mortgage document, and ask a lawyer if you’re on the hook for all of it.

Comment: Also, “duplex” (or “two houses”) might not mean what you think it means.

Comment: Is this one house with two attached living units (what I would call a duplex), or is it two detached houses on the same plot of land?

Comment: See also https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/158700/what-would-be-the-right-way-to-split-the-profits-of-the-sale-of-a-co-owner-prope/158701

Comment: A renter never pays a mortgage anyway. The renter pays the owner who then pays the mortgage. In most situations, the rent doesn't cover the total costs of a house with a loan on it, so the owner has to chip in. (despite what Internet ads about passive income want you to think)

Comment: Read your mortgage document - thoroughly. Looks for terms like "jointly & severally liable" - that means that if payments get behind then the bank can go after whoever they please for the *entire* amount due, not just your share.

Answer (score 1):

If you still own your half, you are normally still on the hook for your share of payments and maintenance. Whether or not you can rent it, and for how much, doesn't change that answer.

An explicit written agreement could, but I'm betting you don't have one, given your question -- or if so that it doesn't change that assumption, since in most circumstances the other owner would be foolish to agree to that.

If you want to not have the responsibilities, sell your share -- to the other owner, or on the open market if your agreement permits that.